# Detectar cuando un cliente(TCP) pierde la conexión

Tags: c#

Estoy utilizando una conexión cliente-servidor (que obtuve de un tutorial publicado en este link https://github.com/enzofjh/Sistema-TCP) in WPF a traves de `sockets` y funciona correctamente para enviar, recibir informacion y saber si el server o el cliente es cerrado.

El único problema es que si el cliente pierde la conexión a internet o local el `event DisconnectNotify()` nunca es invocado y
parece como si todavía estuviese conectado(e.j Si eres el server reconoces cuando el cliente cierra la aplicación pero no cuando el cliente pierde la conexión o desconecta el cable de red.

Si eres el cliente reconoces cuando el server es cerrado pero no cuando pierdes la conexión hacia el ya sea local o internet)
Debido a esto he estado tratando de chequear si el `socket` esta realmente conectado con el método `IsConnected()` pero siempre  devuelve `true`. He probado 3 variantes de  respuestas que he encontrado en este foro a preguntas similares pero no me funcionan.

Gracias de antemano a quien pueda ayudarme. Aquí les dejo una parte del código.

```
//Client:

public class Client
{
    public TcpClient TcpClient { get; private set; }
    public NetworkStream Stream { get; private set; }
    public Thread ReadThread { get; private set; }
    public StreamWriter Writer { get; private set; }

    public delegate void DataCarrier(string data);
    public event DataCarrier OnDataRecieved;

    public delegate void DisconnectNotify();
    public event DisconnectNotify OnDisconnect;

    public delegate void ErrorCarrier(Exception e);
    public event ErrorCarrier OnError;

    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Client() { }

    public bool Connect(string direccionIp, int puerto, string user, string pass, string version)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpClient = new TcpClient();
            TcpClient.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(direccionIp), puerto);
            Stream = TcpClient.GetStream();
            Writer = new StreamWriter(Stream);
            Writer.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", user, pass, version);
            Writer.Flush();
            ReadThread = new Thread(Listen);
            ReadThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            ReadThread.Start();
            return true;
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (OnError != null)
                OnError(e);
            return false;
        }
    }
    // Thread to listen server packs
    private void Listen()
    {
        var lector = new StreamReader(Stream);
        var charBuffer = new List<int>();
        do
        {
            try
            {
                if (!IsConnected()) // Here is where i supose that socket need to be checked
                    break;
                if (lector.EndOfStream)
                    break;
                int charCode = lector.Read();
                if (charCode == -1)
                    break;
                if (charCode != 0)
                {
                    charBuffer.Add(charCode);
                    continue;
                }
                if (OnDataRecieved != null)
                {
                    var chars = new char[charBuffer.Count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < charBuffer.Count; i++)
                    {
                        chars[i] = Convert.ToChar(charBuffer[i]);
                    }
                    var message = new string(chars);
                    OnDataRecieved(message);
                }
                charBuffer.Clear();
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (OnError != null)
                    OnError(e);

                break;
            }
        } while (true);
        if (OnDisconnect != null)
            OnDisconnect();
    }
    public bool IsConnected()
    {
        //variant 1 always return true
        try
        {
            return !(TcpClient.Client.Poll(1, SelectMode.SelectRead) && TcpClient.Client.Available == 0);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // variant 2 always return true
        bool blockingstate = TcpClient.Client.Blocking;
        try
        {
            TcpClient.Client.Blocking = false;
            TcpClient.Client.Send(new byte[1], 0, 0);
            return true;
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            if (ex.NativeErrorCode.Equals(10035)) // WSAEWOULDBLOCK
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            TcpClient.Client.Blocking = blockingstate;
        }
        //variant 3  always return true
        if (TcpClient.Client.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead))
        {
            if (TcpClient.Client.Receive(new byte[1], SocketFlags.Peek) == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

//Server:
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public delegate void ClientCarrier(ClientConnection conexionTcp);
    public event ClientCarrier OnClientConnected;
    public event ClientCarrier OnClientDisconnected;
    public delegate void DataRecieved(ClientConnection conexionTcp, string data);
    public event DataRecieved OnDataRecieved;

    private TcpListener _tcpListener;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //OnDataRecieved += MsgRecived;
        //OnClientConnected += ClientConnected;
        //OnClientDisconnected += ClientDisconnected;
        ListenClients(Settings.Default.ServerIp, Settings.Default.ServerPort);
    }
    private void ListenClients(string ipAddress, int port)
    {
        try
        {
            _tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), port);
            _tcpListener.Start();
            Thread _acceptThread = new Thread(AcceptClients);
            _acceptThread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    private void AcceptClients()
    {
        do
        {
            try
            {
                var conexion = _tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                var srvClient = new ClientConnection(conexion)
                {
                    ReadThread = new Thread(ReadDates)
                };
                srvClient.ReadThread.Start(srvClient);

                if (OnClientConnected != null)
                    OnClientConnected(srvClient);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }

        } while (true);
    }
    private void ReadDates(object client)
    {
        var cli = client as ClientConnection;
        var charBuffer = new List<int>();

        do
        {
            try
            {
                if (!IsConnected())// Here is where i supose that socket need to be checked
                    break;
                if (cli == null)
                    break;
                if (cli.StreamReader.EndOfStream)
                    break;
                int charCode = cli.StreamReader.Read();
                if (charCode == -1)
                    break;
                if (charCode != 0)
                {
                    charBuffer.Add(charCode);
                    continue;
                }
                if (OnDataRecieved != null)
                {
                    var chars = new char[charBuffer.Count];
                    //Convert all the character codes to their representable characters
                    for (int i = 0; i < charBuffer.Count; i++)
                    {
                        chars[i] = Convert.ToChar(charBuffer[i]);
                    }
                    //Convert the character array to a string
                    var message = new string(chars);

                    //Invoke our event
                    OnDataRecieved(cli, message);
                }
                charBuffer.Clear();
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());

                break;
            }
        } while (true);

        if (OnClientDisconnected != null)
            OnClientDisconnected(cli);
    }
    public class ClientConnection
    {
        // Connection Properties
        public TcpClient _TcpClient { get; set; }
        public StreamReader StreamReader { get; set; }
        public StreamWriter StreamWriter { get; set; }
        public Thread ReadThread { get; set; }

        public ClientConnection(TcpClient client)
        {
            try
            {
                NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
                _TcpClient = client;
                StreamReader = new StreamReader(ns);
                StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(ns);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método IsConnected obtiene el estado de la propiedad Connected. Ahora bien, como indican las observaciones en la documentación, esta propiedad refleja el estado de la última operación bajo TCP, por ende, siempre tenes una imagen "Desactualizada".
Según la documentación, la mejor forma de saber si estás conectado o nó, es intentando enviar algo y manejando el caso en el que no.

Te copio la documentación: [TcpClient.Connected Remarks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connected?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

Te copio lo mas relevante:

> Because the Connected property only reflects the state of the
>   connection as of the most recent operation, you should attempt to send
>   or receive a message to determine the current state.